# Prevent child component from unmounting and remounting if parent component changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Problem:

In the code below, when the `Toggle ParentA/B` button is clicked, the `<Child />` component will be unmounted and remounted again, only though effectively only the `Parent` component changed.

**How do I prevent `Child` from unmounting and remounting in such a situation?**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const App = () => {
    const [a, setA] = useState(true)
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setA(!a)}>Toggle ParentA/B</button>
            {a ? <ParentA><Child /></ParentA> : <ParentB><Child /></ParentB>}
        </div>
    )
}
const ParentA = ({ children }) => <div>parentA{children}</div>
const ParentB = ({ children }) => <div>parentB{children}</div>

class Child extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('child did mount')
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('child will unmount')

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>child</div>
        )
    }

}

export default App
```

---

### Replies to potential answers:

> Why not just let the Child component remount since it's only a `<div>` element?

Normally this wouldn't matter if the `Child` component renders cheaply. However, in my case, the `Child` component takes very long to mount, so I cannot afford a remounting every time the `Parent` component changes.

> You could pass the `parentA` or `parentB` string as props to a generic Parent component.

```
const App = () => {
    const [a, setA] = useState(true)
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setA(!a)}>Toggle ParentA/B</button>
            <ParentGeneric content={a? 'parentA': 'parentB'}><Child /></ParentGeneric>
        </div>
    )
}
const ParentGeneric = ({children, content}) => <div>{content}{children}</div>

class Child extends React.Component {
    ...
}
```

This would work. Unfortunately, this restricts my `Parent` component's JSX structure to be identical. In other words, if my `ParentA` and `ParentB`'s JSX structure were different, then I'm not sure how to pass the difference as props.

For example:

```
const ParentA = ({ children }) => <div><div><h1>parentA{children}</h1></div></div>
const ParentB = ({ children }) => <div>parentB{children}</div>
```

If parentA and parentB are defined this way, would it still be possible to abstract these two components into a `ParentGeneric` component and simply passing the structural difference between `ParentA` and `ParentB` as props?

Comment: Give the child components a static key prop?

Comment: @rrd you mean `<div key="child">child</div>`? I've tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like an a/b-problem. If your child component takes so long to mount, then there's presumably something going on there that you could fix. Maybe use react.Context to move expensive bottlneck logic higher up in  the component tree.

Answer (score 8):

**-- Edit --**

It seems my following solution is misleading. I now agree with others in this thread commenting that the requested behavior in the question cannot be achieved. All that I did with my original answer is preventing mount/unmount from running. Still, every time the higher up layout component is changed, the whole contents of the parent component were thrown out and rerendered from scratch.

**-- End of edit --**

There is a way!

It is true that React's [reconciliation algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types) will always mount and unmount children that had their parents replaced (different parent type leads to a whole family branch remounting starting from the changed parent).

However, you can still have the "child" component be presented as a child of some parent layout component, and not mount/unmount when the parent type changes. You'll just need to change the order of the component tree, leveraging the render props pattern:

1. Child (heavy) component is rendered first.
2. Child gets a component prop which will be the parent layout component.
3. Child then renders its parent from props **around itself**, setting itself as its parent's child.
4. Parent is the layout component, rendering it's child component wherever and however you choose!

Example, based on your provided code:

```
import { useState, Component } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setA((prev) => !prev)}>Toggle ParentA/B</button>
      <Child layout={a ? ParentA : ParentB} />
    </div>
  );
};
const ParentA = ({ children }) => <div>parentA{children}</div>;
const ParentB = ({ children }) => <div>parentB{children}</div>;

class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("child did mount");
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("child will unmount");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <this.props.layout>
        <div>child</div>
      </this.props.layout>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/change-parent-no-unmounted-child-nnek0?file=/src/App.js

Check out the console, it works, and is an acceptable practice.

Comment: If you use another component instead of your `div` inside of `Child`, [that component will be remounted](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-parent-no-unmounted-child-forked-bdp5l?file=/src/App.js). Is there a workaround to that, or does this solution only work so long as you are using the native elements and not user-defined components?

Comment: @Shepmaster this is a great point! It seems my solution is misleading, I'll update the answer. Apparently this cannot be done either way, user-defined or with native elements. All that I achieved with my original answer is preventing mount/unmount from running. Still, every time the higher up layout component is changed, the whole contents of the parent component were thrown out and rerendered from scratch.

Comment: Thank you. That's very unfortunate; I'll have to do some ugly hackery to try and fix my original case then...

Answer (score 7):

This isn't much in the way of a technical answer but there *are* reparenting libraries out there which can supposedly accomplish this: [react-reverse-portal](https://github.com/httptoolkit/react-reverse-portal) and [react-reparenting](https://github.com/paol-imi/react-reparenting).

I looked into it myself recently but they are somewhat experimental and it seemed like a lot of overhead to worry about. The answer from @deckele looks like a much better solution if you don't literally need to move the component across multiple branches.

Comment: I was able to get everything I needed with [react-reverse-portal](https://github.com/httptoolkit/react-reverse-portal)! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible, and clearly defined [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#motivation) (emphasis mine):

> There are some generic solutions to this algorithmic problem of generating the minimum number of operations to transform one tree into another. However, the [state of the art algorithms](https://grfia.dlsi.ua.es/ml/algorithms/references/editsurvey_bille.pdf) have a complexity in the order of O(n<sup>3</sup>) where n is the number of elements in the tree.
>
> If we used this in React, displaying 1000 elements would require in the order of one billion comparisons. This is far too expensive. Instead, React implements a heuristic O(n) algorithm based on two assumptions:
>
> 1. **Two elements of different types will produce different trees.**
> 2. The developer can hint at which child elements may be stable across different renders with a `key` prop.
>
> In practice, these assumptions are valid for almost all practical use cases.

If React would've diffed children of different parent types it would've slowed down the whole conciliation process by magnitudes.

So you're left with your proposed solution of a generic parent with props.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the context of this problem, and what larger goal you're trying to achieve it's hard to offer a specific solution.

First, though, it's impossible to prevent the children from unmounting and mounting again, because of the nature of React and the DOM. If you want the DOM nodes to stay there, then the tree structure has to remain the same.

By using this

```
{a ? <ParentA><Child /></ParentA> : <ParentB><Child /></ParentB>}
```

you're actually altering the DOM tree at that level in the tree every time the toggle activates, i.e. you're removing and replacing nodes, which by definition means unmounting and mounting.

To avoid mounting and unmounting of the children, you have keep the DOM tree structure the same on every render, at least as deep in the tree as where the children are.

You can achieve the ***effect*** of what you want, by simply altering the visibility of the parent components based on the toggle, and then using styling to position the containers appropriately, see https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-hawking-61y66?file=/src/App.js

Depending on what you actually want to achieve, you can have the `Child` components as different instances or the same instance. In the case you want the same instance, you would use the `childInstance` rather define the child as JSX directly in the render function. You will see from the console that the children do not mount and unmount on every toggle -- since the DOM tree is not being altered!