# Using dynamically created components without remounting in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a codebase I'm working on, it's pretty common to return non-stable dynamically created React Component from hooks. E.g.:

```
function useSomeHook() {
  const val = useVal();

  return {
    val,
    DynamicComponent: () => {
      doSomething1(val);

      return ...;
    },
  };
}
```

It would be used like:

```
function App() {
  const { val, DynamicComponent } = useSomeHook();
  doSomething2(val);

  return <DynamicComponent />;
}
```

`App` gets `val` from `useSomeHook` instead of rerunning `useVal` because `useVal` might be expensive or it would take effort to refactor.

The issue is that React treats every `DynamicComponent` as a different component, since it's not stable. Every time `App` rerenders, `DynamicComponent` would be remounted. It seems like the only ways to fix this are:

1. Refactor so `useSomeHook` doesn't return a dynamic component
2. Make `DynamicComponent` stable (e.g. wrap it with `useRef`), then use some hack to access the non-stale `val` from the `useSomeHook` scope

Is there another way to fix this by making React treats `DynamicComponent` as the same component after rerendering, even though it's not referentially equal?

Here's a JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fj3Lg1o5/6/

And a related question with a concrete use-case: [React: swap a parent component without remounting the child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66251637/react-swap-a-parent-component-without-remounting-the-child-component)

Comment: Can you not use `useCallback()` to cache this so it doesn't rerender?

Comment: Assuming you mean not including `val` in the dependencies, that would be solution #2

Comment: Would `useMemo` be of any use for your case? https://jsfiddle.net/prg4mdat/