# What is a scalable way to retain state of a child component when the parent changes?

Tags: reactjs

I have a design where a stateful `GrandParent` renders either `ParentOne` or `ParentTwo`, but both parents renders the same stateful `Child` component. When the parent component is changed, I want the state of `Child` to be retained (and its possibly stateful children).

I have created a tiny codepen to show what I mean, and I will also include the JavaScript for future reference in case it disappears:

https://codepen.io/chwallen/pen/WNJRKVB

```js
function Child() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Is state modified: {myState.toString()}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setMyState(true)}>Modify state</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function ParentOne({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="parent-one">{children}</div>
  );
}

function ParentTwo({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="parent-two">{children}</div>
  );
}

function GrandParent() {
  const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = React.useState(true);

  const Parent = isTrue ? ParentOne : ParentTwo;

  return (
    <div className="grand-parent">
      <button onClick={() => setIsTrue(!isTrue)}>Toggle parent</button>
      <Parent>
        <Child />
      </Parent>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<GrandParent />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

In this very simplified case, the solution is to move the `Child` state into the `GrandParent`. However, in the real case, there are more than one `Child` component which is dependent on a second state in `GrandParent`. Each of the child components may be stateful, and they in turn may contain stateful children. Moving all of that state to the `GrandParent` is not scalable. Additionally, I will lose the automagical state reset when the *child*, not parent, is unmounted (which is desirable) if the state is present in the `GrandParent`.

A second option would be to move the rendering of the `Parent` component as far down in the component tree as possible, i.e., each child would render the parent individually. This goes against DRY, and is really only moves the problem from `GrandParent` to the children.

One note: in this example, `ParentOne` and `ParentTwo` could easily be merged and controlled via props. In the real-world application however, these two components are vastly different and **cannot be merged**.

So my question is:

How can I, in a **scalable way**, retain the state for an arbitrary number of stateful children when their parent changes?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57457445/prevent-child-component-from-unmounting-and-remounting-if-parent-component-chang and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66251637/react-swap-a-parent-component-without-remounting-the-child-component

Comment: Depending on your use-case/requirements, you could pass the `Parent` component as a prop to be rendered by the `Child`, and this way the state would, in effect, be higher than then Parent component, and could be maintained. In any way, you need to lift the state higher, because there is no way to change a parent and not un-mount/re-mount all the children.

Comment: Thanks for the links! Yes, that sounds like my second suggestion where each child renders the layout the parent provides as close to the DOM nodes as possible. I just don't like because it breaks DRY, but I guess that is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Store state in the GrandParent component, then pass it down or use context. I would put a context provider in the GrandParent, containing state and memoized control methods, and have a custom `useMyContext` type hook that I can use in the child components to reference/control state changes.